# Simplest way to make a histogram of an unknown, finite list of discrete floating point numbers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, fortran, fortran90

I have a code that generates a sequence of configurations of some system of interest (Markov Chain Monte Carlo). For each configuration, I make a measurement of a particular value for that configuration, which is bounded between zero and some maximum which I can presumably predict before hand, let's call it `Rmax`. It can only take a finite number of discrete values in between `0` and `Rmax`, but the values could be irrational and are not evenly spaced, and I don't know them a priori, or necessarily how many there are (though I could probably estimate an upper bound). I want to generate a very large number of configurations (on the order `1e8`) and make a histogram of the distribution of these values, but the issue that I am facing is how to effectively keep track of them.

For example, if the values were integers in the range `[0,N-1]`, I would just create an integer array of `N` elements, initially set to zero, and increment the appropriate array element for each configuration, e.g. in pseudocode

```
do i = 1, 1e8
    call generateConfig()
    R = measureR() ! R is an integer
    Rhist(R)++ 
end do
```

How can I do something similar to count or tally the number of times each of these irrational, non-uniformly distributed numbers occurs?

Comment: All (finite) floating point numbers are rational.

Comment: One obvious solution is to write the values to a file then postprocess the file to make the histogram.

Comment: If the quantity of interest is a probability density function p(x), I guess you can just divide the interval [0, Rmax] into (say) 100 bins and count the number of samples that fall into each bin...

Comment: @roygvib hadn't thought of that, that might be the easiest way to do it